# Laravel middleware for oAuth in REST API

Tags: php, laravel, oauth

I am making REST API with Laravel 5.3 and I need to make social logins with Google and Facebook. I need to create middleware for that, but I have a problem: I can not find a way to retrieve a user. The problem is: how to detect a provider (Google or Facebook) in `middleware`? I have this code:

```
Socialite::driver($provider)->stateless()->user();
```

But how to detect `$provider`? Or maybe you know another way to retrieve `user`, when there are multiple providers?

Comment: Have you tried laravel socialite plugin?

Comment: https://github.com/laravel/socialite :)